# Is it possible to .split() plucked data in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to split data I'm plucking from a user's post. Currently, it only returns the entire string of data and I cannot break it down any further. I would like to break it down to single words.

["Hello everyone Hello\r\nWhat else can I say?\r\nHello again?"]

Extra thanks if you can get the whitespace removed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't `#split` with a regexp valid for you?

```
var = ["Hello everyone Hello\r\nWhat else can I say?\r\nHello again?"]
var.join.split(/\s+/) # => ["Hello", "everyone", "Hello", "What", "else", "can", "I", "say?", "Hello", "again?"]
```

Comment: Perfect, I've been racking my brain all morning trying to figure it out. Thanks!